# .Net SerialPort Object won't communicate

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Through testing, I have discovered two laptops that refuse to communicate through a .Net SerialPort object. I should probably start off by saying that the application is using .Net 4.0. This is the setup:

- Both laptops communicate using these serial ports with Tera Term
- There is no communication on either the internal serial port on the motherboard or any USB serial port emulators
- The ports being tested were **not** already in use.
- No exceptions are being triggered
- The software can open the COM ports, but not transmit any data
- The ErrorReceived event handler is not being called

Here is how the object is initialized prior to use:

```
serialPort = new SerialPort();
serialPort.PortName = SelectSerialPort.GetSerialPort();
serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
serialPort.DataBits = 8;
serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
serialPort.ReadTimeout = 10000;
serialPort.WriteTimeout = 1000;
serialPort.ErrorReceived += OnSerialError;
```

This setup has been tested on at least twenty other computers and it works just fine. To write to the port I am simply calling:

```
serialPort.Write(packet, 0, nBytes);
```

Where packet is a `byte[]` and nBytes is the length of the data to be sent. It seems like the write timeout is being triggered because the software will open the serial port and after a delay the port closes without transmitting any data.

I was able to capture the following logs with a serial port monitor. The [first log](http://pastebin.com/4KMTBFC2) is what I expect to see, the COM port is opened and configured then the data is sent. The [second log](http://pastebin.com/EcZu6Ngn) is from one of the laptops. You can see the port opens but the port just closes without transmitting anything.

I noticed that there are two main differences in the log files. The log from the laptops contains `RTS off` and the good log does not. Also, the log from the laptops seems to be setting the write timeout to zero. In the good log:

```
Set timeouts: ReadInterval=-1, ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=-1, ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=10000, WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=0, WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=1000
```

And the log from the laptops:

```
Set timeouts: ReadInterval=-1, ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=-1, ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=-2, WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=0, WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=0
```

What could be causing this issue, and what can i do to stop it?

Comment: Since your log points to handshaking as a problem, try again with handshaking disabled.  Probably your signals are slightly outside the acceptable voltage range for RS-232, or don't accept the entire range.  Ports on laptops tend to care about power-saving more than on desktops, and so will probably operate in a lower voltage range of the spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like i have found the solution to this problem while I was doing some research for a different project. I stumbled on a post in the Arduino forum where someone was having a similar issue with an Atmega32U4 (which has a proper USART).

It would seem that there were two properties of the `SerialPort` that I overlooked - `SerialPort.DtrEnable`, and `SerialPort.RtsEnable`.

The winning combination seems to be the following configuration:

```
serialPort = new SerialPort();
serialPort.PortName = SelectSerialPort.GetSerialPort();
serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
serialPort.DataBits = 8;
serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
serialPort.ReadTimeout = 10000;
serialPort.WriteTimeout = 1000;
serialPort.ErrorReceived += OnSerialError;
```

Once these two properties were set to true, communication with no handshaking started working. However, the executable had to be run as Administrator otherwise I would receive an access denied message.